# Calling React Router from vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I have a react single page application using React Router, and having paths defined using Link as shown below:

```
 <Link to="second" className="level-2" params={{id:item.content}} title={item.name}>{item.name}<br/></Link>
```

This changes url from /myapp/firsturi to /myapp/seconduri

Is it possible for me to make the same react router action using vanilla JS? I tried using history.pushState() and history.replaceState() but while the url updates correctly, the content on the page does not. I can get the same thing using window.location.href="/myapp/seconduri" but that causes a page refresh which is not what I want.

Any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

This has worked for me:

```
// simulate navigation to where you want to be (changes URL but doesn't navigate)
window.history.pushState("","","/url");
// simulate navigation again so that
window.history.pushState("","","/url");
// when you simulate back, the router tries to get BACK to "/url"
window.history.go(-1);
```

Everything else I tried was just forcing the DOM to reload again as if it was a link click.

Answer (score 3):

React Router relies on the `history` module to handle locations. When the page loads it parses the initial URL, which is why setting `window.location.href` works.

The history that you use includes a `listen` function which React Router uses to listen for location changes. When one occurs, it will trigger a re-matching of the new location against your routes, which in turn will render the correct components.

Manually calling `pushState`/`replaceState` does not trigger the listening function, which is why your app is failing to update. Instead, you should use your history instance to [navigate](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md).