# Navigate to Angular app from email

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, nginx

We have a **.NET** back-end, **Angular 5** application and **nginx** server. After you register your account in application, you receive an email with verify link, which looks like this:

`[root]/register/verify?userId=blabla&code=blabla`

After clicking on link I want to be navigated to the Angular app but instead it fails on server and all you can see is **nginx** 404 error page.

But when you first navigate to index page `[root]`, Angular app starts and when you manually attach to base url this part `/register/verify?userId=blabla&code=blabla`, it will work => service is called and the email verified.

If I get it right, angular app is not running when you navigate from outside and thus nginx is trying to process the url and fails miserably. I've tried some tweaks on Angular side, followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42519497/3359635) but without success.

I guess the only solution is some nginx setting, am I right? An if so, what do I have to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that route, `/register/verify` is controlled by Angular Router. Well, when you use routing in angular, you must make sure that your server can handle all routes your Angular routes does, and make sure that you return the HTML file containing the Angular App.

I assume that you're not doing this, so that route does not resolve in your webserver, hence the error.

Anyway, your use case is a bit strange. Why do you handle a verification in the client side? What I'd do would be to have .NET controller handle that request, and then, depending on the result of the validation, redirect to the angular app, maybe with a route to indicate if everything went OK or there was an error.

In any case, you should make sure that every route that ins't handled by the server, or returns an static file, returns the HTML page of your angular app, so the Angular router can handle it.

If you don't this, if a user navigates through the app, and then, for some reason, reloads the page, they'll encounter the same error

Comment: Good point about the weird use case. I guess we didn't think that piece through.

Answer (score 0):

Angular apps are typically SPA (single page applications) where application handles all the routes itself. The server needs to be configured in a way to return `index.html` for the 404 responses. Very often `index.html` is copied to `404.html`, or nginx/node server handle that on the fly.

I strongly recommend taking a look at the official documentation for deployment and server settings: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll forward it to our back-end guys